# Reverse DNS lookup inside a network extension

Tags: objective-c, swift, network-programming, macos-catalina

I am writing a content filter with the NetworkExtension framework on macOS. (NEFilterDataProvider).

Inside this code, I can see the IP addresses that are used. How can I get the domain name from these IPs in an efficient way ?
Ideally there would be a way to do it with a swift (or objective-c framework) so that I can do it easily. If not, how to access the dns cache on macOS?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has pretty detailed documentation on this [available here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/ResolvingDNSHostnames.html), and also [some sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/CFHostSample/Listings/CFHostSampleSwift_HostNameQuery_swift.html).

The basic steps are:

To resolve a host with CFHost:

1. Create a CFHostRef object by calling CFHostCreateWithAddress.
2. Call CFHostSetClient and provide the context object of your choice and a callback function that will be called when resolution completes.
3. Call CFHostScheduleWithRunLoop to schedule the resolver on your run loop.
4. Call CFHostStartInfoResolution to tell the resolver to start resolving, passing kCFHostNames as the second parameter to indicate that you want it to return hostnames.
5. Wait for the resolver to call your callback. Within your callback, obtain the results by calling CFHostGetNames. This function returns an array of CFDataRef objects, each of which contains a POSIX sockaddr structure.

The main part of starting this process is like this, from Apple's example code. self.host is the CFHost that you've created from the address:

```
func start() {
    precondition(self.targetRunLoop == nil)
    self.targetRunLoop = RunLoop.current
    
    var context = CFHostClientContext()
    context.info = Unmanaged.passRetained(self).toOpaque()
    var success = CFHostSetClient(self.host, { (_ host: CFHost, _: CFHostInfoType, _ streamErrorPtr: UnsafePointer<CFStreamError>?, _ info: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) in 
        let obj = Unmanaged<HostNameQuery>.fromOpaque(info!).takeUnretainedValue()
        if let streamError = streamErrorPtr?.pointee, (streamError.domain != 0 || streamError.error != 0) {
            obj.stop(streamError: streamError, notify: true)
        } else {
            obj.stop(streamError: nil, notify: true)
        }
    }, &context)
    assert(success)
    CFHostScheduleWithRunLoop(self.host, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode.rawValue)
    
    var streamError = CFStreamError()
    success = CFHostStartInfoResolution(self.host, .names, &streamError)
    if !success {
        self.stop(streamError: streamError, notify: true)
    }
}
```